# How do I create MVEL evaluation context?

Tags: mvel

I want to sequentially parse MVEL as follows:

```
HashMap myData = new HashMap(){{ put("x", 1); }}

eval("y = 2", ...) // assign value to y
...
eval("x + y", myData, ...) // expect 3
```

Is this possible?  If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just share the variable resolver across expression evaluations:

VariableResolverFactory vars = new MapVariableResolverFactory(new HashMap(){{ put("x", 1); }});

MVEL.eval("y = 2", vars):
MVEL.eval("x + y", vars);

Comment: Thanks.  MVEL is very handy but like so many open source components the documentation could be improved.